# Get information from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

When I click on artikle It needs to diretct me to page.php where I display whole article.
Problem is im not sure how to with $_GET superglobal var properly take information. I have to get ID with $_GET.

I already have included database in my index.php where I displayed several articles.

Im sending id like this:

```
 echo '<a href="clanak.php?  class="form-field-textual"  id='.$row['id'].'">';
```

//article.php

```
    <?php
 $servername = "localhost:3306";
 $user = "root";
 $pass = "";
 $dbo = "projekt";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $pass, $dbo);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM projekt";


if ($conn->query($sql)===TRUE) {
  $specID=$conn->insert_id;

        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " .
 $row["kategorija"]. " " . $row["naslov"]. "<br>";

    } else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$row_id = $row['id'];
echo '<a href="clanak.php?id='.$row_id.'" class="form-field-textual">some text</a>';

        <?php
     $servername = "localhost:3306";
     $user = "root";
     $pass = "";
     $dbo = "projekt";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $pass, $dbo);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

      $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : '';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM projekt WHERE id = $id";

    if ($conn->query($sql)===TRUE) {
      $specID=$conn->insert_id;

            echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " .
     $row["kategorija"]. " " . $row["naslov"]. "<br>";

        } else {
      echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
```

Comment: That code displayed this

 $row_id = $row['id']; echo 'some text'; 0 results

Comment: This is a good start but this code also have some issues like: `projekt` is the name of the data base and not the name of the table to query; The code is not protected against query injection; it is better to get globals via `filter_input` and not directly from `$_GET`;

Comment: This is part of the task, later I'll protect it from sql injection

Comment: $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : '';

try to inject something to query :)

topicstrarter do not ask about fully completed code with safe query building