# Using ID to display article with php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I know I have to get id by $_GET but i dont know how to do it properly. Every time this $id=$_GET var doesnt work properly

This is my html:

```
echo '<a href="clanak.php?  class="form-field-textual"  id='.$row['id'].'">';
```

And php:

```
<?php include 'connect.php'; 
         define('UPLPATH', 'images/'); 
         echo"Success";



        $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM articles");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
        {
            echo '<a href="#">'.htmlspecialchars($row['id']).'</a>';
       }

 ?>
```

Comment: Why is `class="form-field-textual"` in the middle of href?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/62278985/1839439